# Is this map $\mathbb Q(x, y) \to \mathbb Q((t))$ well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

I am trying to find a map $\mathbb Q(x, y) \to \mathbb Q((t))$ and I have tried the map given by $x \mapsto \sum_{i > 0} t^i$ and $y \mapsto t^{-1}$. I know there is no ring map $\mathbb Q(x, y) \to \mathbb Q(t)$, so I need to use some infinite series somewhere in the definition, which lead me to this idea. Is this map well-defined?

Comment: The idea is reasonable, but not the details. Note that $\sum_{i>0} t^i = \tfrac{t}{1-t} = \tfrac{1}{t^{-1}-1}$. Thus, your map would sent $x$ and $\tfrac{1}{y-1}$ to the same place. Then what would your map do to $\left( x-\tfrac{1}{y-1} \right)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Ah, you are right. How can I find two elements of $\mathbb Q((t))$ algebraically independent over the image of this map?

Comment: Or specifically is there a direct approach to find two elements to map $x$ and $y$ to without guessing?

Comment: You can map everything in ${\bf Q}(x,y)$ to zero in ${\bf Q}((t))$. But presumably you have in mind some properties you would like your map to have?

Comment: @algebraist As a follow up to your remark, try $x\mapsto e^t$ and $y\mapsto e^{t^2}$.

Answer (score -1):

Map $x \mapsto \displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!}$, the Taylor series of $e^t$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What about $y$?